# lodash - project/transform object into key value array

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm about to use `forOwn` to iterate through an object's properties and create an array manually and can't helping thinking there's a oneliner already available to do it.

```
{ 
  prop1 : "value",
  prop2: { sub:1}
}
```

to:

```
[ 
   {key: "prop1", value: "value"},
   {key: "prop2", value: {sub:1}}
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use lodash's [_.map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) with [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015):

```js
const obj = { 
  prop1 : "value",
  prop2: { sub:1}
};

const result = _.map(obj, (value, prop) => ({ prop, value }));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.2/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can do it using [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) with [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const obj = { 
  prop1 : "value",
  prop2: { sub:1}
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).map(([prop, value]) => ({ prop, value }));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I've marked this as the answer as it fits my problem using lodash as requested.  However, I've added a _.map to jsperf page comparing them. http://jsperf.com/loop-for-in-vs-object-keys-foreach/19 (excuse the additional snippet someone has added for the array op - completely ruined the test), but when comparing the forOwn with map, there's no real benefit to it

Comment: The benefit is not in the performance, but in "oneliner already available to do it" as you requested :) Anyhow, remember that the difference in performance is only noticeable in a very large amount of items, and if that is not the issue go with `_.map()` as it's more readable (at least for me).

Comment: `Object.entries` is only available in ES2017, so if using ES2015 (ES6), it's not possible.

Comment: why is it: 
`const result = _.map(obj, (value, prop) => ({ prop, value }));` 
and not: `const result = _.map(obj, (prop, value) => ({ prop, value }));` ?

Comment: Because when lodash's map passes the key (`prop`) as the 2nd param.

Answer (score 13):

You don't even need lodash for that:

```
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key){
  return { key: key, value: obj[key] };
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer, interestingly Object.keys is slower than forOwn.  http://jsperf.com/loop-for-in-vs-object-keys-foreach/19  - someone's ruined the test by adding some array ops to it, but look at Object.keys vs _.forOwn vs the new one i've added _.map

Comment: @sambomartin Of course it will be "faster" since internally lodash just uses `while` loop for iteration. But then again, the question never asked for performance but for something that's already available.

Answer (score 10):

A little bit of ES6 :

`_.map( obj, (value, key) => ({key,value}) )`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pairs` if it fits your case:

```
_.pairs({ 'barney': 36, 'fred': 40 });
// → [['barney', 36], ['fred', 40]]
```

Ref: https://lodash.com/docs#pairs

Comment: But it doesn't fit his case.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **lodash/fp** you can use `_.entries`

```js
const a = { one: 123, two: { value: 'b' }};

const pairs = _.entries(a).map(p => ({ key:p[0], value: p[1] }))

console.log(pairs)
// [
//   {
//     "key": "one",
//     "value": 123
//   },
//   {
//     "key": "two",
//     "value": {
//       "value": "b"
//     }
//   }
// ]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash-fp/4.15.0/lodash-fp.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In response to Ori's comment and for completeness, I've posted the _.forOwn version.  It's marginally faster but you need to declare the array first (not-a-one-liner).

```
var arr = [];
_.forOwn(obj,function(item, key) {
    arr.push({ property : key, value : item});
});
```

Comment: @ori this is the forOwn version. thanks for your help. (http://jsperf.com/loop-for-in-vs-object-keys-foreach/19)