# Transform object to array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a object like that:

```
var days = {
  0: 10,
  1: 40
  2: 20, 
  3: 15,
  4: 5,
  5: 18, 
  6: 9
};
```

I need to transform it to something like that:

```
var days2 = [
  {0:10},
  {1: 40},
  {2: 20},
  {3: 15},
  {4: 5},
  {5: 18},
  {6: 9},
];
```

I know that it's easy, but I don't have any idea

Comment: Please share your attempt.

Comment: It's `days).map`.

Comment: Wouldn't `var days = [10, 40 20, 15, 5, 18, 9];` be even better?

Comment: it should be `Object.keys(days).map( s => {return {[s]: days[s]} })`

Comment: This might already be answered. You can use lodash. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100692/lodash-project-transform-object-into-key-value-array/32104942)

Answer (score 2):

You could take all entries of the object and build new objects with key/value pairs.

```js
var days = { 0: 10, 1: 40, 2: 20, 3: 15, 4: 5, 5: 18, 6: 9 },
    result = Array.from(Object.entries(days), ([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
 Object.keys(days).map( key => {return { [key]: days[key]
```

```js
var days = {
  0: 10,
  1: 40,
  2: 20, 
  3: 15,
  4: 5,
  5: 18, 
  6: 9
};
var output = Object.keys(days).map( key => {return { [key]: days[key] } });

console.log(output);
```