# Conversion object into array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to combine these two object array into one object array with combining each property with their own values.

```
var a ={'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[2,3,4,5]}

to [{'a':1,'b':2},{'a':2,'b':3},{'a':3,'b':4},{'a':4,'b':5}]
```

How can I achieve this using `lodash` library?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please don't ask for solutions without trying to solve the problem yourself first. If you have tried something, please share in your question what it is that you have tried.

Comment: I checked all the default lodash methods if any are there but couldnt find..

Comment: Checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100692/lodash-project-transform-object-into-key-value-array  But there the value is not an array so wanted a help how to do it throuh lodash

Comment: Lodash is a nice little toolbox but you don't necessarily _have_ to use it. This is perfectly doable with a few lines of Javascript.

Comment: Hi can you pls help me out with the normal js way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the values for one of the keys, and then for each value—iterate over all the keys. This can be done in pure JavaScript fairly easily.

e.g. `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` for key `a`, then loop over they keys: `[ 'a', 'b' ]`

**Note:** You will see the parameter `'_'` (underscore) used as the first parameter for the mapping below. This represents the current value in the list for the value of key `'a'`. It is meaningless, but we need to have it there to access the next parameter (index of current value).

```js
// Code Golf - zipObjects (100 bytes)
var z=a=>(x=>a[x[0]].map((_,i)=>x.reduce((o,k)=>Object.assign(o,{[k]:a[k][i]}),{})))(Object.keys(a))

function zipObjects(arr) {
  return (keys => {
    return arr[keys[0]].map((_, valueIndex) => {
      return keys.reduce((obj, key) => {
        return Object.assign(obj, {[key] : arr[key][valueIndex]});
      }, {});
    });
  })(Object.keys(arr));
}

console.log(zipObjects({ 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 5] }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

#### With lodash

You can declare a plugin function very similarly.

```js
_.mixin({
  'zipObjects' : function(arr) {
    return (keys => {
      return _.map(arr[_.head(keys)], (value, valueIndex) => {
        return _.reduce(keys, (obj, key) => {
          return _.assignIn(obj, {[key] : arr[key][valueIndex]});
        }, {});
      });
    })(_.keys(arr));
  }
});

console.log(_.zipObjects({ 'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [2, 3, 4, 5] }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```